# How does DriverManager gets the instance of jdbc driver class

Tags: java, design-patterns, jdbc

`Class.forName` is used to instantiate the driver class. 
`Class.forName` do not have an object, it simply instantiates the driver class instance.If that is the case , how will DriverManager class get the reference of the instantiated driver class ?

Comment: Note however, that this is no longer necessary for JDBC 4.0 Drivers, as they should register themselves via META-INF/services: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class.forName("X") causes the class named X to be dynamically loaded,
basically a call to forName("X") causes the class named X to be initialized (i.e., JVM executes all its static block after class loading).

To answer your question JVM executes the static block and the driver registers itself with the DriverManager.

This process is very well explained in following link:
http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17

Answer (score 1):

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) for the `Driver` Interface.

It says,

> When a Driver class is loaded, it should create an instance of itself
>   and register it with the DriverManager. This means that a user can
>   load and register a driver by calling
>
> Class.forName("foo.bah.Driver")

Answer (score 0):

from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

> When the method getConnection is called, the DriverManager will
>   attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at
>   initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader
>   as the current applet or application.

drivers loaded at initialization:: DriverManager class will attempt to load the driver classes referenced in the "jdbc.drivers" system property

drivers loaded explicitly:: by  Class.forName("driver.name");